# ImageMagick: resize with borders in batch

Tags: imagemagick, image-resizing, mogrify

I have a few images I want to convert in batch using ImageMagick.

All images should be converted to a specific width, lets say `500px`.

- If an image's width is larger than `500px`, scale it down and preserve the aspect ratio.
- If an image's width is less than `500px`, add borders to the sides to make it `500px` wide.

The first one is possible using `magick mogrify -resize 500x *`, but this also scales images with a smaller width up. How can I prevent that from happening and add borders instead?

I figured I could just add `-background black -gravity center` but I don't know how to prevent upscaling.

Comment: Make a COPY of a few files and try using `-resize 500x^>`

Comment: Great! That worked when I added `-extent 500x` too. So my final command was `magick mogrify -resize '500x^>' -background black -gravity center -extent 500x *`. If you add your comment as an answer I'll accept it!

Comment: Oh... This crops images which are more than `500px` wide, which is not what I want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it using two separate commands for now:

Resize images larger than `500px` wide:

```
magick mogrify -resize '500x>' *
```

Add borders to images smaller than `500px` wide:

```
magick mogrify -gravity center -extent '735x<' *
```